# CACHE access method

Tags: sas, sas-stored-process

I'm debugging a Stored Process Web Application that writes a PDF to `_webout`.

I'd like to avoid the following ERROR when running in a workspace session:

```
ERROR: Function is only valid for filerefs using the CACHE access method.
```

I've tried `filename _webout temp` and `filename _webout dummy`, to no avail.

Any tips from the field?

Comment: Is it correct to assume you are putting the debug information as content in the produced pdf?

Comment: Not adding any specific debug info - just wanted to run the STP in a batch session in order to retain library mappings / intermediate datasets etc.  The ERROR wasn't preventing this, but it was distracting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
filename _webout cache;
```

That seems to work in my version, but I have no idea where the output goes.

Comment: ha ha - nice!  Don't see it in the documentation - but works a treat.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah, I looked through the doc multiple times trying to find it.  SAS is full of undocumented features like this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to check the engine type of the _webout fileref and avoid using the header functions if the xengine is STREAM.

This macro serves:  https://core.sasjs.io/mf__getxengine_8sas.html

Usage:

```
    %if %mf_getxengine(_WEBOUT)=STREAM %then %do;
      /* set header function */
    %end;
```